# How to move all files within subfolders into a new folder using bash?

Tags: bash, shell

I have a folder that I downloaded all my fonts to. When I opened the folder i noticed they were saved out into subfolders.

Is there a bash-shell script to grab all the files within the subfolders and move them to the parent folder?

Comment: `mv */* .` ? So what have you tried?

Comment: To be completely honest I haven't tried anything yet. I was hoping there would be an answer somewhere out there. My bash knowledge hasn't been improved since first learning the basics

Comment: or `find /path/to/parent -type f -execdir mv '{}' /path/to/parent +` (it goes without saying that the files should all have unique names)

Comment: So I tried David's code but I'm getting stuck right after I run it because it's saying  `find: -execdir: no terminating ";" or "+"` I feel like I'm missing something that I dont know :/ (p.s. I really appreciate all your help)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can move files with same extensions recursively using the wildcards. e.g. if you want to move all log files in nested folders under `log/` directory into `backup/` directory, you can use the following command:

```
mv log/**/*.log backup/
```

Comment: Thank you so much! So I'm sure there is a better way to do this on all my font files. I'm not sure they all have the same extension.

Comment: So don't specify the extension. `mv log/**/* backup`.